# Visual Studio Code: Select each occurrence of find

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, azure-data-studio

I'm looking for a "select each occurrence of" something I'm trying to find. For example a file has a bunch of text that includes "abc", I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and type `abc`. I can either find the first one or the next one, but I would like to "multi-cursor" each one in the file.
I've already found the feature that lets me highlight text and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to get the next that matches the selection, but if there's a hundred of these things - well that gets quite tiresome.

Comment: on a mac, after find, you need `⌥⮐`

Answer (score 235, accepted):

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>** Select all occurrences of current selection

```
editor.action.selectHighlights
```

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>**   Select all occurrences of current word

```
editor.action.changeAll
```

Please refer for more information [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dauren-akilbekov . Is there any difference between `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`L` and `Ctrl`+`F2`?

Comment: Is there a case sensitive version of `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `L` ?

Comment: @jokerster You can toggle case sensitivity in editor by `alt+c` (while the editor where the text you want to match is focused), this will change the behavior of various selection/find tools.

Comment: For large files, there is a limit of 1000 "cursors". So, you may have to modify you text more than once.

Comment: The number of cursors has been limited to 10000.

Comment: On Mac, it'll be Shift-Cmd-L – [official reference cheatsheet for macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)

Answer (score 120):

**<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>** Select all occurrences of find match

```
editor.action.selectAllMatches
```

This has the added benefit of working with Regular Expression searches, since selecting occurrences of a word of a selection cannot leverage the Regex functionality.

Comment: This is the answer I needed, because this allows me to select a subset of matches within an already selected block.

Comment: VS Code needs a UI button for this! Vote for it here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20453

Answer (score 41):

I know this thread is here for a while now, but I think this will be helpful:

This thread on Github talks exactly about it: 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/5715

Summary:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> → Open find widegt.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> → Turn on regex mode.
3. Input search text → Regex text or normal text.
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> → Select all matches.
5. Left arrow → Adjust cursors. (Ignore this step if you don't want to edit the selected text.)
6. Edit text → Do what you want. (Ignore this step if you don't want to edit the selected text.)
7. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> → Select modified text. (Ignore this step if you don't want to edit the selected text.)
8. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> → Copy selected text.
9. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> → Open a new tab.
10. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> → Paste.

Answer (score 31):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will select all occurrences of word in the document 
**BUT**
there is another way to selecting them growingly: 
if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> it will selects the second match, it you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> again  it will match the third one and so on ....

Comment: In mac Ctrl + d is duplicating the line

Comment: It is Cmd+d in mac

Comment: Is there a similar shortcut like CTRL+D but for Visual Studio (not VS Code) ?

Comment: to be honest, i never used visual studio code ever , sorry

Comment: That's what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 12):

For Mac User:

<kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Select all occurrences of the current selection

<kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> Select all occurrences of the current word

Comment: If one of the default shortcuts isn't working (or is performing another action), this can be because an extension you've installed has overridden the default shortcut.

You can establish which extension by opening Keyboard Shortcuts with Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S and in the search box at the top, type `Ctrl+Shift+L`.

There you should see what's using that keyboard combination and you can remove or change it as desired.

Answer (score 10):

For mac users:

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

<kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> is what worked for me for VSCode on Windows 10.

While  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> just opened some Language selector.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac:

1. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>** to open the find menu in top right:

[image]

2. Select the third option within the input and add the regex you want to match.
3. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>** to select all items that match.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching in a single file, use simple search using **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>**, then even if you close the search box, simply keep pressing **<kbd>F3</kbd>** to go to next match and so on. **<kbd>F3</kbd>** just repeats previous search and selects your next match.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for - I wanted to select all occurrences at once to edit them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to Place Multiple Cursors at the End of All Your RegEx Finds

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is what you're after (Thanks to **[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark)**). Also note [Rodrigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62834179/3018212) has a nice step-by-step guide with explanations as well.

#### Full step by step example with [keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Note, this work with [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio) as well.

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Find)
2. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (`toggleFindRegex` command)
3. `'\d+'` (what to look for)
4. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (add cursors; `editor.action.selectAllMatches` command)

   - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> *(`editor.action.selectHighlights` command) also works here*
5. <kbd>ESC</kbd> (`closeFindWidget` command)

Now the following text should have [four blinking cursors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_multi-cursor-selection) (at the daggers ), where you can edit to your s content!

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Location] (key, longName, shortName, oldRegion, contactId, email, city, state, zip, isActive)
VALUES
('GEORG','Georgian College','GEORG','1A','1271','globalint@school.edu','Barrie','ON','L4M 3X9','1'),
('LOYAL','Loyalist College','LOYAL','2A','1271','globalint@school.edu','Belleville','ON','K8N 5B9','0')
-- etc.
```

To find this or similar **keybindings** open the [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) and search for `findWidget` for commands used with `CTRL` + `F`, or `searchViewlet` for commands used with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F`.