# How to select every N line in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, textselection

How can I select every N lines in visual studio code.
I can't find a proper regualr expression can let me do this.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to select it by cursor or what?

Comment: I want to use multiple cursors on my document for editing(extracting), which the data I need is in every other line or every N line.

Comment: @Charles How big is your data? Large or small?

Comment: quite large, up to few thousands lines

Answer (score 62):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
2. If not already enabled, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to toggle RegEx searching (or press the `.*` button).
3. Enter `(.*\n){N}` into the search field, replacing `N` with the number of lines to select (such as `(.*\n){2}` for every second line).
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> or `Select All Occurrences of find Match` from the command palette to select every Nth grouped lines.
5. Press <kbd>←</kbd> to place the cursor at the beginning of every Nth line, or <kbd>→</kbd> then <kbd>←</kbd> to place the cursor at the end of every Nth line.

[image]

Comment: Is there a Mac equivalent for the `ALT+ENTER`?

Comment: Hey @n8udd, on mac it's also `alt+enter`, or `option+return`

Comment: instead of `alt+enter` can from command palate select `Select All Occurrences of find Match`

Comment: Thanks @MohammadHosseinAmri! I'll add that to the answer

Answer (score 16):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Check the regex icon `.*`
- Search: `(^.*?$[\n]){9}`

That RegExp will find [ed. but **not** select] 9 lines of code at a time - empty lines do count as a line.

What are you going to replace them with?

---

If you want to replace every nth line, like every 9th line with some new text, try this regex:

`((.*\n){8})(.*\n)`

and replace with `$1[new line 9 stuff here]`

Comment: Thanks Mark, but for this one I can only replace it with something. If I want to copy the content by multiple cursor does it work as well?

Comment: Oddly, I cannot find an option to select the current "find" occurrence, only all finds via Alt+Enter
Select All Occurrences of Find Match
editor.action.selectAllMatches    Does anyone know of a "selectCurrentMatch" command?

Comment: If you use a regex, you can wrap a selection you want to reference later in round brackets. ([a-z]+)\w+. Then use it in the 'replace' with $1. So '$1 my new string'.

Comment: You can combine this regex with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36008779/1945782), to select the number of required lines.  Perfect!

Answer (score 10):

**Select Multi lines in VsCode**

Visual code natively supports this functionality.

But you have to select the lines manually.

1. Hold the alt button and click where you want to select the data

[image]

2. You can also select multiple lines
   [image]

For more details:[Visual Studio Code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_selection-multicursor)

Comment: Thanks Hamza, do you know can i do it via keyboard?
Because I have few thousands lines of code, anyway to do it faster?

Comment: @Charlez The selection will be after every N lines or N can vary?

Comment: Correct. The selections are having the pattern. Every N line, which N can be varied.