# How do I select all find matches within selection?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I am searching for a regular expression and have enabled "find in selection". Now I want to select all the matches that I found. My problem is that if I use "Select all occurrences of find match" from the command palette, then it repeats the search for the entire file and selects all of those occurrences.

How do I limit "Select all occurrences of find match" to only the matches that  were within my original selection?

Comment: **See Also**: [Visual Studio Code: Select each occurrence of find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35992145/1366033)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `editor.action.selectAllMatches` : currently bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! Does this have a corresponding command in the command palette?

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on **Linux** and **Windows**
- <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> on **MacOS**